# Check if address exists before use/jump in assembly?

Tags: assembly, memory-address

Say I have loaded some random address like `0x00001234` into `eax`. Is there a way to test that this address is valid/exists before jumping to it or dereferencing it?
Or do I have to implement an exception handler?

Comment: Exactly why are you trying to jmp to 'random' addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if your operating system lets you take over the page fault mechanism, that's easy to do. Just implement your own fault handler, temporarily store a `ret` instruction at that address, then just `call` to that location.

You'll have to set a flag in the handler to indicate it was invalid (either for writing the `ret` or trying to execute it), and you'll need to replace the original contents if it was valid.

Alternatively, you could possibly walk the IDT/GDT/LDT tables to see if your address exists within any of them.

Good luck finding an OS that allows either of these to be done by mere mortals :-)

Perhaps if you could tell us *why* you want to do this, rather than just assuming this is the best way to achieve what you want, we could think of another solution.

Comment: This is does indeed sound like an exceedingly bad idea. Still, Win32 does provides a IsBadCodePtr function for the purpose

Comment: It is worth noting that the `VERR` and `VERW` instruction may do the trick depending on the context (since "valid" and "exists" have little sense within the concept of address)